# Error when assigning return value of ReadAllLines to variable

Tags: vb.net

I am currently struggling with this function in Visual Studio:

```
Private Sub dlsuc()
    Dim file_ As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\v.txt"
    Dim file As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file_)
End Sub
```

I can't get this to work, I get something like these error messages:

> Error 1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand? `ReadAllLines` returns an array.

Comment: I have edited your question and tried to improve it. Formatting was mostly fine, I just removed an unnecessary `<blockquote>` tag. I tried adding an actual question, but it's still a bit fuzzy. The title is much more specific now. I have removed the very unspecific [tag:variables] tag and introduced the [tag:vb.net] tag. Usually, you'd want to have more and more specific tags, but I couldn't really find more suitable ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `File.ReadAllLines()` returns an array of strings. You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Instead, try it like this:

```
Private Sub dlsuc()
    Dim file_ As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\v.txt"
    Dim file As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(file_)
End Sub
```

Notice the `()` in the variable declaration.